# What's the difference between 'down' and 'rm' in docker/docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

The docs for [`docker-compose down`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/), [`docker-compose rm`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/rm/), and [`docker rm`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rm/) all read very similarly.  What's the difference? And when would you use one over the others?

Comment: You can `up` something that's been shut `down`, but not if you `rm` remove it.

Comment: @tadman: I just tested, and that's incorrect. I can `rm` and then `up` an image. It deletes and recreates the image's container, which is the same as doing `down`+`up`, as far as I can tell

Comment: You may want to check if that removes any ephemeral data or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- "**docker-compose down**": stop and remove the container with all the networks (but not volumes), you should add -v option to do that.
- "**docker-compose rm**": remove stopped only containers, but not running containers, you should add option -s to be able to remove running containers

Now, the diffrence between "**docker-compose rm**" and "**docker rm**", is that when you make changes affecting the container in the docker-compose.yml file, you can't remove the container created by the old docker-compose.yml using "docker-compose rm", so in this case you should use "docker rm" to do that.

If you still don't get it, you can try this example:

1. Run a container using "docker-compose up"
2. Now stop the container without removing it using "docker-compse stop"
3. Change the name of the container in the docker-compose.yml
4. Run "docker-compose up" --> a new container will be created with the new name.
5. Now if you try to remove the old container using "**docker-compose rm** old_container_name", you will get this error: No such service.
6. In this case you can only remove the old container using "**docker container rm** old_container_name".

Answer (score 0):

[rm](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/rm/) - Removes stopped service containers.

[down](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/) - Stops containers and removes containers, networks, volumes, and images created by up.

Comment: Yes, I read these exact sentences in the docs, but I don't understand the difference.  When would you want to use one vs the other?  And what about the two different `rm`s?

Comment: No difference between the rm's as far as I know, there are many docker commands which docker-compose just does the same thing as. The difference between down and rm is pretty apparent though, if you still don't get that, try removing a running container. Then try downing it.

Comment: Let's have an example. Assume you have your docker services with large volumes (consider your databases inside the volume) and those are static - you don't wanna get rid of them - but you do wanna rebuild the services. Here, instead of removing everything with `down` (that includes Volumes, which recreating them may take a long time), you just `rm` them (remove the services, but the volumes are already there to use them with the new `up`)